# Jquery select a sub set of text boxes

Tags: jquery

I am using asp.net to render a page consisting of numerous sets of text boxes.

The number of groups depends on the customer, so it is not in my control.

what I want is so that when teh values in the entry boxes in a group are changed, then the result box for that group changes to sum the total of the group, and also change the back colour.

I have got this working for a prototype of one set, as per below.

```
function calculateSetColour(i) {
        var total = 0;

        $(".answer").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                total += parseFloat(this.value);           
            }
        });


        $(".result").val(total);
        $(".answer").addClass(calculateColour(total));
    }
```

But I cant seem to get it to work for groups. I assume that I need to add in say a second selector, so I can then use

```
$(.answer .group" + i).each ..
```

where i is the id added programatically to each group. But putting an alert statement inside the function shows that it is never being hit, so I suspect I have the syntax wrong and the selector is never matching.

So is my approach correct, and what is the right syntax to incorporate a variable into the class selector? (Class selectors are safest as .net can mangle id's and names)

As requested, the html looks like

```
 <div class="reportItem">
            TOTAL UNITS DELIVERED<BR />
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl01_Name">Site A</span>
        <div class="l1" >New</div><div class="l2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptdG$ctl01$tbNew" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl01_tbNew" class="answer" onblur="calculateSetColour(1);" /></div> <br />
        <div class="l1" >Used</div> <div class="l2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptdG$ctl01$tbUsed" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl01_tbUsed" class="answer"  onblur="calculateSetColour(1);" /></div>
        <div class="l1" >Compliance</div> <div class="l2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptdG$ctl01$tbCompliant" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl01_tbCompliant" class="result" /></div>
            </div>


                    <div class="reportAltItem">
                        TOTAL UNITS DELIVERED<BR />
        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl02_DlrName">Site 2</span>
    <div class="l1" >New</div><div class="l2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptdG$ctl02$tbNew" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl02_tbNew" class="answer" onblur="calculateSetColour(2);"/></div>
    <div class="l1" >Used</div><div class="l2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptdG$ctl02$tbUsed" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl02_tbUsed" class="answer" onblur="calculateSetColour(2);"/></div>
                        <div class="l1" >Compliance</div> <div class="l2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptdG$ctl02$tbCompliant" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl02_tbCompliant" class="result" /></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you show some sample HTML (not .net source)

Comment: Would grouping by the wrapping class work for you, such as  <div class="reportAltItem"> ?

Comment: Unfortuantely not, there may be 10 groups, 5 would be item, 5 would be altitem so I can have different colours in the groups.

I may be able to programatically add another class to that div if thats the best way of solving this. At present I was trying to pass a group id in via the onblur, and looking at adding the id into each class inside teh group, but I guess that is inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited :

```
function calculateSetColour(input) {
    var total = 0;

    var outerDiv = $(input).parent().parent();
    outerDiv.find(".answer").each(function () {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            total += parseFloat(this.value);           
        }
    });


    outerDiv.find(".result").val(total);
    outerDiv.find(".result").addClass(calculateColour(total));
}
```

then call it :

```
<div class="reportItem">
        TOTAL UNITS DELIVERED<BR />
    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl01_Name">Site A</span>
    <div class="l1" >New</div><div class="l2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptdG$ctl01$tbNew" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl01_tbNew" class="answer" onblur="calculateSetColour(this);" /></div> <br />
    <div class="l1" >Used</div> <div class="l2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptdG$ctl01$tbUsed" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl01_tbUsed" class="answer"  onblur="calculateSetColour(this);" /></div>
    <div class="l1" >Compliance</div> <div class="l2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rptdG$ctl01$tbCompliant" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptdG_ctl01_tbCompliant" class="result" /></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. Initially, the reportItem and reportAltItem divs are added by the framework. I may be able to programmatically add in a unique name to that div, but if the div was

    <div class="reportItem group1"> would your solution still work (by using "group1" or "group2" in the blur of course)

Comment: Ok, removed the need to know the outer div's class name, which didn't look right anyway

Answer (score 0):

Give the Group the same class name and include the group + id (Ex. group may represent 10 inputs). Put the group + id in the lang property of the input...

```
//example: <input class='group group1' lang='group1' />
//on blur get lang and pass that specific group. 
$(".group").blur(function () {
  var thisgroup = $(this).attr("lang");
calculateSetColour(thisgroup);
```

});

Pass the group name to the function. At this point we know that group1 class exists. The each looks like this:

```
function calculateSetColour(group) {
    var total = 0;

    $("." + group).each(function () {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            total += parseFloat(this.value);           
        }
    });


    $(".result").val(total);

    //update the color for this specific group...
    $("." + group).addClass(calculateColour(total));
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear enough. I have say 10 groups of this data on a page, but I only want to trigger the colour change for the group that has been edited. If I just have the class of "answer" then changing any of them will update all the groups.